# Read Multiple Files in ascending order File Name

Tags: java, file

I dont know what is happening to me. I want to access a directory with multiple files in it suppose:

```
 folder\\1.txt 2.txt 3.txt....
```

now I want to read them according to their occurrence I mean first comes the lowest simply I want to read them in ascending order!
My code is:

```
File f=new File("xxx");
File[] files = f.listFiles(); 
for (File ff : files) {

   if(ff.isFile()) {
   System.out.println(ff.toString());
   }
}
```

so far the code works fine but it takes the files as

```
1.txt
10.txt
11.txt
9.txt
8.txt
...
```

so what is going wrong i want to read them orderly in ascending order

Comment: Remember, the order in which files a returned from Files%#listFiles is undefined. Also remember, when sorting Strings, they are sorted in natural order, which is not the same as numerical order, you will need to supply a custom Comparator which be passed to Arrays.sort, which will order the files in numerical orde

Comment: Or even more simply, name them with enough leading zeros so they sort correctly automatically, e.g. 000000001.txt, 00000002.txt, ...

Answer (score 1):

just sort by ***Arrays.sort***:

```
        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {

            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                int n1 = getNum(o1.getName());
                int n2 = getNum(o2.getName());
                return n1 - n2;
            }
       }

        private int getNum(String name) {
            int i;
            // extract number from the file name here by doing some processes
            return i;
        }
```