# How to read & write values from file in ascending order in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, io, file-handling

There is a question somewhat related in [Read Multiple Files in ascending order File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319033/read-multiple-files-in-ascending-order-file-name) which pertains to reading multiple files in Ascending order in Java. However, I am stuck in a situation where I am not able to read files in an ascending order. I have a folder with multiple text files ranging from `"0001_FileNameUnique.txt"` to `"0272_FileNameUnique.txt"`.

I am able to read the files and append the value I need to a list using this:-

```
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/WindTurbine_AccidentDataset/News_txt.txt"
from pathlib import Path
all_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.txt' in f] # note: if statement to only get .txt files
new_list = []

for fle in all_files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
   with open(os.path.join(path, fle),"rb") as f:
      text = f.read()
      new_list.append(text)

new_list = [item.decode(encoding='latin1') for item in new_list]
```

However, clearly the value written to `new_list` are not in the ascending order, and I would like the values to be written in an ascending order (so that files re read in ascending order in the for loop too). Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Based on the idea by @Finomnis in the accepted answer, the following solution worked like a charm:-

```
for fle in sorted(all_files):
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
   with open(os.path.join(path, fle),"rb") as f:
      text = f.read()
      new_list.append(text)
```

Comment: create a loop for values between 0001 to 0272 prepend it to _FileNameUnique and check whether the file exists if the file exists do the necessary things you want to do.

Comment: If you use `sorted`, I would even go one step further and instead do `all_files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.txt' in f])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sorting?

```py
all_files.sort()
for fle in all_files:
   ...
```

Comment: It gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: My bad. Fixed. Forgot that sort() doesn't return the sorted array, but sorts in place.

Comment: I used for fle in sorted(all_files):
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
   with open(os.path.join(path, fle),"rb") as f:
      text = f.read()
      new_list.append(text) and It worked. Thanks for your idea though which helped me reach there! I am accepting this as the answer too

Comment: Yah, `sorted()` also works. In your case no big difference. `.sort()` doesn' create a new array, so it is a little less resource hungry. But your list of files most likely doesn't contain more than 1 million file names, so it doesn't matter.